# Azure CLI doesn't recognize some Powershell commands

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm running the following code in my Azure CLI on an uploaded Powershell script:

```
Install-Module AzureAD.Standard.Preview

Connect-AzAccount -UseDeviceAuthentication
Connect-AzureAD
```

It will recognize the first two commands, but it will not recognize the `Connect-AzureAD` command. I have to manually type it into the CLI for it to work.

Does anyone know why this occurs and how I can run the `Connect-AzureAD` command from a powershell script?

Comment: What do you mean by not recognize the command? `Connect-AzureAD` with no arguments should open a popup browser to authenticate and block there. Sounds like you're looking for unattended script, if so you will need a service principal

Answer (score 0):

Could be due to Azure AD modules being deprecated for Microsoft graph.

> Azure AD, Azure AD Preview and MSOnline PowerShell modules are planned for deprecation. Microsoft Graph PowerShell is the PowerShell module to use for interacting with Microsoft Entra ID and other Microsoft services.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/migration-steps?view=graph-powershell-1.0